Matplotlib: making subscripts italicized
I'm using plt.text to display some texts in my figure. I want the whole text to be italicized, including subscripts. I've tried a number of ways and I just can't get the subscript to be italicized. Here's an example of what I tried. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
text0 = r'Base: c$f_1$'
text1 = r'Method 1: c$f_{1}$'
text2 = r'Method 2: cf$_{\it 1}$'
text3 = r'Method 3: cf$_{\mathit{1}}$'
plt.text(0,0.2,text0)
plt.text(0,0.4,text1,style='italic')
plt.text(0,0.6,text2,style='italic')
plt.text(0,0.8,text3,style='italic')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

enter image description here

It seems that it works (with mathit ) for letters but not numbers!

Bummer, appreciate the response though.

perhaps using plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True can help here (although that might be overkill, and will likely affect other elements of your figure).
